# Metabase : Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.10.3 from/to central

Tags: clojure, metabase, maven-central, maven-repository

I am building Metabase (branch = release-0.41.0) using Cooperate Jenkins.

Could you please guide me on how to use my corporate remote repository instead of this https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ for downloading dependency & library?

Could you please suggest a configuration(deps.edn files) change in Metabase 0.41 version to replace my corporate remote repositories with Maven central or remote repo access?

````
13:44:06  org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.10.3
13:44:06    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
13:44:06    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
13:44:06    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
13:44:06    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.extensions.maven$fn__1053.invokeStatic(maven.clj:132)
13:44:06    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.extensions.maven$fn__1053.invoke(maven.clj:122)
13:44:06    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:244)
13:44:06    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha$expand_deps$children_task__746$fn__748$fn__749.invoke(alpha.clj:406)
13:44:06    at clojure.tools.deps.alpha.util.concurrent$submit_task$task__479.invoke(concurrent.clj:34)
13:44:06    at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
13:44:06    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
13:44:06    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
13:44:06    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
13:44:06    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
13:44:06  Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.10.3 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, repo1.maven.org/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)```
````

Comment: https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#_maven

Comment: Do you use leiningen, boot or clj deps? Please post the matching manifest files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.